# tidyverse pubh's cross_tab - doesn't recognize column name

Tags: r, tidyverse

Hi I have a dataframe of COVID symptoms and COVID diagnosis:

EDITED TO ADD PACKAGES

```
library(tidyverse)
library(pubh)
library(sjlabelled)



    dta <- structure(list(fever = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), nose_bleed = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    chills = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), decrease_taste = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), cough = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), decrease_smell = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), shortness_breath = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), decrease_test_smell = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), fatigue = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), nausea = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), appetite_loss = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), abdominal_pain = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    muscle_ache = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), diarrhea = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), joint_ache = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), rash = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), sore_throat = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    chest_pain = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), runny_nose = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), headache = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), conjunctivitus = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), seizure = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), wheezing = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), altered_consciousness = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), other_respiratory_symptom = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    other_symptom = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), covid19 = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("COVID-19 Positive", "COVID-19 Negative"
    ), class = "factor")), row.names = c(169L, 252L, 312L, 515L, 
161L, 136L, 365L, 463L, 572L, 194L, 443L, 444L, 88L, 500L, 96L, 
353L, 171L, 310L, 51L, 206L, 307L, 59L, 87L, 561L, 89L, 216L, 
542L, 239L, 298L, 140L, 132L, 529L, 242L, 338L, 115L, 369L, 22L, 
418L, 179L, 366L, 86L, 70L, 135L, 44L, 254L, 507L, 535L, 16L, 
575L, 466L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to make a cross_tab this way:

```
dta %>%
  select(c(fever,   nose_bleed,
        chills, decrease_taste,
        cough,  decrease_smell,
        shortness_breath,   decrease_test_smell,
        fatigue,    nausea,
        appetite_loss,  abdominal_pain,
        muscle_ache,    diarrhea,
        joint_ache, rash,
        sore_throat,    chest_pain,
        runny_nose, headache,
        conjunctivitus, seizure,
        wheezing,   altered_consciousness,
        other_respiratory_symptom,  
        other_symptom)) %>%                                              
  copy_labels(dta) %>%
  cross_tab(covid19 ~ .) %>% 
  theme_pubh()
```

But I am getting this error.  I have no idea why and Googling the error/?cross_tab got me nowhere...  Any insight would be appreciated.

```
 There is no column named ' covid19 ' in data  data 
Error in if (x$show.all == TRUE) out = x$res else out = x$res[1:(length(x$res) -  : 
  argument is of length zero
```

I know the first one isn't actually an error.  But, the function refuses to acknowledge that column.
The second one is an error but I don't know if it's related.

Comment: Thanks @akrun I just edited it to include that.  Sorry to forget in the first place!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't reproduce the error with the same data using `labelled`

```
library(dplyr)
library(pubh)
library(labelled)
dta %>%
  select(c(fever,   nose_bleed,
        chills, decrease_taste,
        cough,  decrease_smell,
        shortness_breath,   decrease_test_smell,
        fatigue,    nausea,
        appetite_loss,  abdominal_pain,
        muscle_ache,    diarrhea,
        joint_ache, rash,
        sore_throat,    chest_pain,
        runny_nose, headache,
        conjunctivitus, seizure,
        wheezing,   altered_consciousness,
        other_respiratory_symptom,  
        other_symptom)) %>%                                              
  copy_labels(dta) %>%
  cross_tab(covid19 ~ .) %>% 
  theme_pubh()
```

-output

```
                           ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                                                                            covid19                   
                                                                 COVID-19 Positive   COVID-19 Negative         Total  
                                                                             (N=6)              (N=44)        (N=50)  
                                   ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                     fever                                                                            
                                     - 0                                6 (100.0%)          39 (88.6%)    45 (90.0%)  
                                     - 1                                 0 ( 0.0%)           5 (11.4%)     5 (10.0%)  
                                     nose_bleed                                                                       
                                     - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                     chills                                                                           
                                     - 0                                6 (100.0%)          41 (93.2%)    47 (94.0%)  
                                     - 1                                 0 ( 0.0%)           3 ( 6.8%)     3 ( 6.0%)  
                                     decrease_taste                                                                   
                                     - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                     cough                                                                            
                                     - 0                                6 (100.0%)          42 (95.5%)    48 (96.0%)  
                                     - 1                                 0 ( 0.0%)           2 ( 4.5%)     2 ( 4.0%)  
                                     decrease_smell                                                                   
                                     - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                     shortness_breath                                                                 
                                     - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                     decrease_test_smell                                                              
                                     - 0                                6 (100.0%)          43 (97.7%)    49 (98.0%)  
                                     - 1                                 0 ( 0.0%)           1 ( 2.3%)     1 ( 2.0%)  
                                     fatigue                                                                          
                                     - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                     nausea                                                                           
                                     - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                     appetite_loss                                                                    
                                     - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                     abdominal_pain                                                                   
                                     - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                     muscle_ache                                                                      
                                     - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                     diarrhea                                                                         
                                     - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                     joint_ache                                                                       
                                     - 0                                6 (100.0%)          43 (97.7%)    49 (98.0%)  
                                     - 1                                 0 ( 0.0%)           1 ( 2.3%)     1 ( 2.0%)  
                                     rash                                                                             
                                     - 0                                6 (100.0%)          39 (88.6%)    45 (90.0%)  
                                     - 1                                 0 ( 0.0%)           5 (11.4%)     5 (10.0%)  
                                     sore_throat                                                                      
                                     - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                     chest_pain                                                                       
                                     - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                     runny_nose                                                                       
                                     - 0                                6 (100.0%)          43 (97.7%)    49 (98.0%)  
                                     - 1                                 0 ( 0.0%)           1 ( 2.3%)     1 ( 2.0%)  
                                     headache                                                                         
                                     - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                     conjunctivitus                                                                   
                                     - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                     seizure                                                                          
                                     - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                     wheezing                                                                         
                                     - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                     altered_consciousness                                                            
                                     - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                     other_respiratory_symptom                                                        
                                     - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                     other_symptom                                                                    
                                     - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                   ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

    Column names: , COVID-19 Positive, COVID-19 Negative, Total
```

#### Update

If we do this with `sjlabelled`, it `select` only the columns specified in `select`.  We can include the 'covid19' column as well (on a fresh `R` session with only relevant packages loaded)

```
library(sjlabelled)
library(dplyr)
library(pubh)
dta %>%
   select(c(fever,   nose_bleed,
         chills, decrease_taste,
         cough,  decrease_smell,
         shortness_breath,   decrease_test_smell,
         fatigue,    nausea,
         appetite_loss,  abdominal_pain,
         muscle_ache,    diarrhea,
         joint_ache, rash,
         sore_throat,    chest_pain,
         runny_nose, headache,
         conjunctivitus, seizure,
         wheezing,   altered_consciousness,
         other_respiratory_symptom,  
         other_symptom, covid19)) %>% 
         copy_labels(dta) %>%
         cross_tab(covid19 ~ .) %>% 
   theme_pubh() 
                               ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                                                                        covid19                   
                                                             COVID-19 Positive   COVID-19 Negative         Total  
                                                                         (N=6)              (N=44)        (N=50)  
                               ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                 fever                                                                            
                                 - 0                                6 (100.0%)          39 (88.6%)    45 (90.0%)  
                                 - 1                                 0 ( 0.0%)           5 (11.4%)     5 (10.0%)  
                                 nose_bleed                                                                       
                                 - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                 chills                                                                           
                                 - 0                                6 (100.0%)          41 (93.2%)    47 (94.0%)  
                                 - 1                                 0 ( 0.0%)           3 ( 6.8%)     3 ( 6.0%)  
                                 decrease_taste                                                                   
                                 - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                 cough                                                                            
                                 - 0                                6 (100.0%)          42 (95.5%)    48 (96.0%)  
                                 - 1                                 0 ( 0.0%)           2 ( 4.5%)     2 ( 4.0%)  
                                 decrease_smell                                                                   
                                 - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                 shortness_breath                                                                 
                                 - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                 decrease_test_smell                                                              
                                 - 0                                6 (100.0%)          43 (97.7%)    49 (98.0%)  
                                 - 1                                 0 ( 0.0%)           1 ( 2.3%)     1 ( 2.0%)  
                                 fatigue                                                                          
                                 - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                 nausea                                                                           
                                 - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                 appetite_loss                                                                    
                                 - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                 abdominal_pain                                                                   
                                 - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                 muscle_ache                                                                      
                                 - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                 diarrhea                                                                         
                                 - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                 joint_ache                                                                       
                                 - 0                                6 (100.0%)          43 (97.7%)    49 (98.0%)  
                                 - 1                                 0 ( 0.0%)           1 ( 2.3%)     1 ( 2.0%)  
                                 rash                                                                             
                                 - 0                                6 (100.0%)          39 (88.6%)    45 (90.0%)  
                                 - 1                                 0 ( 0.0%)           5 (11.4%)     5 (10.0%)  
                                 sore_throat                                                                      
                                 - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                 chest_pain                                                                       
                                 - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                 runny_nose                                                                       
                                 - 0                                6 (100.0%)          43 (97.7%)    49 (98.0%)  
                                 - 1                                 0 ( 0.0%)           1 ( 2.3%)     1 ( 2.0%)  
                                 headache                                                                         
                                 - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                 conjunctivitus                                                                   
                                 - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                 seizure                                                                          
                                 - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                 wheezing                                                                         
                                 - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                 altered_consciousness                                                            
                                 - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                 other_respiratory_symptom                                                        
                                 - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                                 other_symptom                                                                    
                                 - 0                                6 (100.0%)         44 (100.0%)   50 (100.0%)  
                               ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

Column names: , COVID-19 Positive, COVID-19 Negative, Total
```

Comment: Thanks for responding...I have slightly different packages loaded - tidyverse and sjlabelled rather than dplyr and labelled.  Could that be it?

Comment: Oh @akrun it still happened when I just load dplyr.

Comment: @JensabbyATL please check my updated solution

Comment: @JensabbyATL No.  It is not that case.  I would have assumed that after `copy_labels(dta)` it returns the full data, but it didn't